# Tags (and wikis) needed!

Tags: discussion, tags

There are currently [<s>89</s> **30 untagged questions**](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) floating around. That's *crazy!* These questions need tags, useful tags, tags that'll help folks find them.

And those tags need wikis. Because if they don't have wikis, tags used by only 1 question will be destroyed after 6 months. Which is *probably* how we got in this situation to begin with... A good wiki describes how the tag should be used, clarifies any ambiguities that might exist in what it refers to, provides resources for askers and generally just looks nice.

Anyone care to help edit these?

Comment: *"**if they don't have wikis**, tags used by only 1 question will be destroyed after 6 months"* Can you explain where the qualifier in bold came from? I've never heard of that until just now.

Comment: @Rainbolt [See this meta suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700/) which got implemented in 2013: single tags no longer expire if they have a wiki. We've been actively using this for a while on RPG.SE to prevent system tags from being deleted when there's only one question about that system: [Save our system tags!](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3067/1204)

Comment: @doppelgreener Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Voted to close [this question](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/15012/6692) instead of retagging.

Answer (score 6):

In order to ensure these tags **survive,** we need to make sure each one has either **a second question**, or **one question and a tag wiki.** This is relatively easy for those with editing privileges, less simple for those who have to suggest edits and wait. I think we can work together though.

## How can we create these together?

We've got two tasks: creating the tags and keeping them alive.

**Tag creation:** When a tag needs rescue, add it to the list below, along with a link to the question it's attached to so we can recreate the tag later if necessary. **Those who must suggest edits,** please suggest edits then add them to this list. **Those with edit privileges,** please take the time to rescue the tag at the same time if you can.

**Tag rescue:** Look through the below tags, and create wikis for them or find second questions from them. Please remove tags you rescue from this list, **but only when your edits are approved.** (i.e.: unlike tag creation, where you should add it when you propose the edit.)

**If this list is getting long, please take some time to do some tag rescues rather than tag creations! :)**

## Tags needing action

- [buffy-the-vampire-slayer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buffy-the-vampire-slayer) [Sunrise vs. "Summon Eclipse" in Buffy the Vampire Slayer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/455/sunrise-vs-summon-eclipse-in-buffy-the-vampire-slayer)
- [puzzle-strike](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-strike) [How does DeGray's Pilebunker chip work when trashing Gems of size 2+?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/2/how-does-degrays-pilebunker-chip-work-when-trashing-gems-of-size-2)
- [labyrinth](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/labyrinth) [Is 3-4 player endgame necessarily a deadlock?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/9070/3389)

  - Needs tag synonym [the-amazeing-labyrinth](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-amazeing-labyrinth). Maybe this should be the primary one?
- [x-files-ccg](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-files-ccg) [Typo in the Women's Health Clinic, Richville, MD card?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/4086/3389)

Also check out the list of [new tags](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new), since many of them are created without a wiki.

Comment: @Rainbolt I'll help create them too. We've got some time to create those tag wikis. But this is not personally pointed at you, it's also to make sure others don't miss that bit.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems like it's tough for low rep users to help with this because tags can't be created without editing a question, meaning they'll have to wait a few hours for their edit to go through before they can add a tag wiki :-(

Comment: @Thunderforge I've reformulated this answer. Please use it as your resource to help you add tags and create wikis for them later!

Comment: @Rainbolt I've reformulated this answer into something more productive. And now that I've about finished moving house, I'll get to work adding some wikis. :)

Answer (score 4):

Some of the tags the questions need already exist and just need to be added to the question. I will start working adding tags to questions on that list a couple each day.

--

Got some more done today and getting close to the level where I can add the tags without needing a review which should help get them done faster.