# Can't find the game "Wild Cards", so can't fill out the tag wiki

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

We've had a number of calls for adding tag wikis (e.g. [Tags (and wikis) needed!](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1254/3389)), since tags without wikis are destroyed after 6 months if they are only linked to one question. Recently, I came across [Looking for rules to a card game called "Wild Cards"](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/8534/3389) and changed it from [untagged](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) to the newly created [wild-cards](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wild-cards). Naturally, I wanted to add a wiki to prevent the tag from being deleted in 6 months.

However, I found that I am unable to find anything about this game. The question asker describes it as a game that is played in groups of four across several tables. However, the only ones [listed on Board Game Geek](https://boardgamegeek.com/geeksearch.php?action=search&objecttype=boardgame&q=wild%20cards&B1=Go) are:

- [A 2005 game](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/18109/wild-cards) for 2-6 players that does not appear to have been released in English
- [A 2013 game](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/173358/wild-cards) that is more a collection of rules for 52 card decks, and was published after this question was asked
- [A series of decks](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgamefamily/20510/wild-cards) for 2-6 players that are just ways to play Memory, Old Maid, and Go Fish.

Without being able to find out anything about this game (assuming that the name is correct), I have no way to write a tag wiki for it, and the tag will be deleted in 6 months.

What should I do in this situation?

Comment: I'm actually voting to close the question you're referring to as unclear. I'm not even sure they're describing a board or card game so much as some kind of rotating format someone came up with styled after speed dating. Whatever it is, we have just about *no* passable detail about it to identify it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That question is essentially asking for us to identify a game, where all we have to go on is the name they think they remember and some of the rules. So, it should be tagged with [identify-this-game](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-game).

Unless we know that a game exists, we should not make a tag for it.

Comment: I agree with this strongly enough I've made that change. It *is* an identify-this-game question. But we're also not sure whether the game they're looking for *is* one called wild cards, that could've just been the name someone used after they forgot the original name - which would explain their difficulty finding the rules. Like you point out, we're not even sure it exists. Naturally we can't really have a tag for this, if we don't know what on earth the thing is that we're tagging. (Granted, if the meta finds differently, the change can yet be un-made fairly easily.)